# Transparent UITableViews not scrolling correct

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, transparent

I am using a `UITableView` in my App. There is no special coding, nor special IB settings for this table. Once I set the background transparent by:

```
myTableView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor]
```

my Tableview can not be scrolled correctly anymore. If you hit the text in the TableView or an image, it scrolls fine but if I touch between the textlines or an empty cell, it does not scroll or bounce.

This happens on the Simulator (iOS 6.0,5.1,5.0 iPhone or iPad) and my devices iPhone 4,4S,5 and iPad with XCode 4.5

A surprisingly and odd solution was to use `[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.1 alpha:0.1]` instead of `[UIColor clearColor]`. Using 0 instead of 0.1 will have the same issue.

Adding a transparent background view to the TableView has the same effect.

Does anybody have the same issue or another solution on how to make a UITableView transparent ?